# Logical OR of arrays in javascript

Tags: javascript

I would like to perform a logical OR operation on arrays in javascript, so that performing this operation on arrays `a` and `b`

```
let a = [0,1,0]
let b = [0,0,5]
```

gives me

```
OR(a, b)
[0,1,5]
```

What would be an efficient and idiomatic way to implement `OR`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could reduce the wanted arrays by taking a mapping and an `or` function.

```js
const or = (a, b) => a || b,
      mapped = fn => (a, b) => a.map((v, i) => fn(v, b[i]));

var a = [0, 1, 0],
    b = [0, 0, 5],
    c = [a, b].reduce(mapped(or));

console.log(c);
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use `||` operator in combination with `map` method by passing a *callback* function as argument.

```js
let a = [0,1,0]
let b = [0,0,5]

let c = a.map((item, index) => item || b[index]);
console.log(c);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the arrays always have the same length, use `.map` and `||`:

```js
const OR = (a, b) => a.map((aItem, i) => aItem || b[i]);
let a = [0,1,0]
let b = [0,0,5]
console.log(
  OR(a, b)
);
```